# Modulus at its finest(what is definition of modulus?)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Found this question on a previous exam:

What is the answer of the following expression?

$$(1!+2!+3!...+100!)\pmod{18} =$$

The answer $0$ isn't right!

If you know the answer please explain me it step by step.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Note that you only need to add the first $5$ terms.

Comment: Which factorials are multiples of $18$? Only the others count.

Comment: The answer is 9?

Comment: Basically what we are doing is (1!)mod18 + (2!)mod18 + (3!) mod18 ... + (100!)mod18?

Comment: And then take the remainder of the sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, if $18$ divides $n!$, then you can ignore that particular term. Now, $18$ divides $6!$ and therefore any factorial greater than or equal to $6!$. So we are left with $1!+2!+3!+4!+5!=1+2+6+24+120 \equiv 9\pmod {18}$.